# AWS Load Balancer with a https listener created with terraform throws connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb, terraform-provider-aws

I am facing a ridiculous behavior from the AWS Load Balancer created by terraform. After creating the target groups, which they point **healthy**, I create the load balancer as following:

```
resource "aws_alb" "jira_elb" {
  name               = "${data.vault_generic_secret.atlassian_datacenter_aws_jira.data["jira_elb_name"]}"
  internal           = "${local.elb_internal}"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  idle_timeout       = 600
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.jira_elb_sg.id}"]
  subnets            = "${local.elb_internal == "true" ? local.private_subnet_ids : local.public_subnet_ids}" // Set the subnets based on local variable
  enable_deletion_protection = false # CHANGE!!
  enable_cross_zone_load_balancing = true
  access_logs {
    bucket   = "${data.vault_generic_secret.atlassian_datacenter_aws_jira.data["jira_elb_s3_logs_bucket"]}"
    prefix   = "jira-elb"
    enabled  = true
  # interval = 20 //The publishing interval in minutes. Default: 60 minutes.
  }
}
```

And the https listener:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "jira_https_elb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn  = "${aws_alb.jira_elb.arn}"
  port               = "443"
  protocol           = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy         = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn    = "${data.aws_acm_certificate.jira_ssl_certificate.arn}"
  default_action {
    target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.jira_target_group.arn}"
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

After the load balancer is created and try to access it through the browser I retrieve *connection refused*. The ridiculous part is that if I delete the listener by hand, and create the same listener with same certificate, port, and forwarding the DNS work through the browser. Is there any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Having the same issue with ARN, remove ssl_policy and certificate_arn put hard coded. like `certificate_arn:arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:*********`

Comment: Have already made these changes but unfortunately did not help

Answer (score 3):

AWS Load Balancer with an https listener created with terraform

```
resource "aws_lb" "internal_alb" {
  name               = "INTERNAL-ALB"
  internal           = true
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  security_groups    = ["${aws_security_group.ecs_sg.id}"]
  subnets            = ["subxxxx", "subnet-dcxxxx", "subnet-fxxxx"]
  enable_deletion_protection = false

  access_logs {
    bucket  = "bucket_name"
    enabled = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "INTERNAL-ALB"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "web_alb_target_group" {
    name                = "WEB-TG"
    port                = "80"
    protocol            = "HTTP"
    vpc_id              = "${aws_lb.internal_alb.vpc_id}"

    health_check {
        healthy_threshold   = "5"
        unhealthy_threshold = "2"
        interval            = "30"
        matcher             = "200"
        path                = "/heartbeat"
        port                = "traffic-port"
        protocol            = "HTTP"
        timeout             = "5"
    }

    tags = {
      Name = "WEB-TG"
    }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "internal_alb_http" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.internal_alb.id}"
  port              = "80"
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:48xxxxxxx:targetgroup/WEB-TG/4ad42b3dadxxxxxx66"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "internal_alb_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.internal_alb.id}"
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
  certificate_arn   = "arn:aws:iam::48xxxxxxx:server-certificate/certifcate"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:48xxxxxxx:targetgroup/WEB-TG/4ad42b3dadxxxxxx66"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "node" {
  zone_id = "ZSxxxxxxx"
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  alias {
    name                   = "${aws_lb.internal_alb.dns_name}"
    zone_id                = "${aws_lb.internal_alb.zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

Comment: To see current recommended ssl_policy, check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies. Right now, in aug 2023, it is "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS13-1-2-2021-06"